# Changing background of a cell based on the value of another

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I need the background of a cell to change based on the value (1, 2, 3, 4, or 5) in a different column and row. For example, if cel `A4 == 4`, then cell `C19` will have a red background.

Comment: What do you want to store in the formatted cell (`C19` in your example)?

Comment: I do not want any data, just color.  It is to notify the user to not book that time.  That being said, I don't want to deny booking the time since the user has to be allowed to use their own judgement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)?

A code like this can give you ideas for their solution:

```js
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C4')
    if (e.value === '4') e.source.getRange('C19').setBackground('red');
    else e.source.getRange('C19').setBackground('');
}
```

Comment: I tried using your code and no luck.  I have used scripts before, but I am having trouble with this code.  Anything I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement seems very modest and I'm guessing you would like other colours or more complex criteria but I think the image 'says it all' as far as red fill in C19 if A4=4:

[image: SO19735346 example]

This is accessed via Format, Conditional Formatting...

The bottom right-hand corner may be relevant. I'm using New Google Sheets that has much more powerful CF facilities than its predecessor.